# Visual Studio 2015 closes when I right click on the editor

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Whenever I right-click an editor window in Visual Studio 2015 it closes instantly. Not just the editor window, it closes the whole IDE.

Someone has ever seen it before? If so, what can I do?

**UPDATE:** forgot to mention that I had several unloaded projects in the solution. It didn't seem to matter in the first moment, but it turned out making difference.

Comment: If everything you try doesn't slove the problem, try to reinstall the lastest update (update 3 for now). It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to "solve" the issue.

I had a solution with several projects and a lot of them were unloaded, as I didn't need them for the console application I was working on. The solution has some console applications, a lot of class libraries and one web application.

After some trial and error I found that when **I reload the web application** Visual Studio started working as expected. No, the console application doesn't reference the project. It looks like an actual VS bug.